# R/Shiny/Leaflet: capture and record a user's geolocated position

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Using a Easybutton, I created a button in a Shiny-Leaflet environment, which zooms and pans the map to the user's geolocated position. An working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("map"))


server <- function(input, output, session) {

 output$map <- renderLeaflet({
 leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                   options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%

  addEasyButton(
    easyButton(
      position = "topleft",
      icon = "fa-crosshairs",
      title = "Locate Me",
      onClick = JS(
        c(
          "function(btn,  map){map.locate({setView:true,enableHighAccuracy: true })}"
        )
      )
    )
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

This works fine. However, I want to capture the lat/long of the user's geolocated position into a input variable. This functionality exists for a mouse click on the map, in which case the lat/long of the clicked position is stored in 'input$map_click'. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point you could observe the map bounds changing, and return the centre of the bounds

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("map"))


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%

      addEasyButton(
        easyButton(
          position = "topleft",
          icon = "fa-crosshairs",
          title = "Locate Me",
          onClick = JS(
            c(
              "function(btn,  map){map.locate({setView:true,enableHighAccuracy: true })}"
            )
          )
        )
      )
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_bounds, {
    event <- input$map_bounds

    lat <- mean(event$north, event$south)
    lon <- mean(event$west, event$east)

    print(paste0("map center - lat: ", lat, ", lon: ", lon))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

However, you'll get the coordinates everytime the map is panned. You could maybe work this into being observed only when the button is pressed, although at the moment I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: How did you determine `input$map_bounds`?

Comment: @zacdav - I found it while going through the [source code](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/23754d43e1c7ebbd19167d3b1970d9e3849baecd/javascript/src/index.js#L33)

Answer (score 0):

I found another opportunity myself, by following these procedures and adding JavaScript logic.

http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/2017/03/14/4-tricks-for-working-with-r-leaflet-and-shiny/